# Run program from command line what prompts password and automatically provide password for it (cmd.exe, python)

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I have command line program what prompts password:

```
> cwrsync root@NN.NN.NN.NN:/src /cygdrive/c/dst
```

Output (when i run it from cmd.exe command line):

```
root@NN.NN.NN.NN's password:
```

When i input password manually, all OK. Output:

```
skipping directory src
```

I want to provide password for it from command line or python script automatically.

I tried:

One. From command line:

```
> echo pass|cwrsync -r root@NN.NN.NN.NN:/src /cygdrive/c/dst
```

Not working. Output:

```
root@NN.NN.NN.NN's password:
```

Two. From python script. test.py:

```
import subprocess
cmd = "cwrsync -r root@NN.NN.NN.NN:/src /cygdrive/c/dst"
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
std1, std2 = proc.communicate("pass")
print std1print std2
```

Not workin. Output:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [Receiver=3.1.1]
```

Answer (score 2):

It is common that security oriented programs ask for password on direct io instead of reading stdin. And as :

```
echo pass|cwrsync -r root@NN.NN.NN.NN:/src /cygdrive/c/dst
```

did ask password, I presume that csrsync directly reads from console.

In that case you cannot automate it without some work and low level programming, because you will have to simulate keyboard actions. You should instead search the documentations, because as it looks like it uses an underlying `ssh`, it is likely to accept a public key pair. If it accept one without passphrase, you should be able to automate it.

Comment: Sending keyboard input is relatively easy to do using Python's ctypes module to call `WriteConsoleInput`. I just did this today as an example for testing the getpass module. But I agree that using a public/private key pair is a simpler and more secure way to automate this.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a newline in your stdin string `communicate` call like so:

```
import subprocess
cmd = ['cwrsync', '-r', 'root@NN.NN.NN.NN:/src', '/cygdrive/c/dst']
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, 
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                        shell=True)
std1, std2 = proc.communicate("pass\r\n\r\n")
print std1
print std2
```

You should also see if it works with `shell=False` (from [subprocess docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)):

> Using `shell=True` can be a security hazard. See the warning under [Frequently Used Arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) for details.