# How to send the password after user name in command prompt using python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, subprocess

Trying to run some windows application in a specific user mode. After passing the command, it will ask for password. So passing the password using proc.communicate() but its not working, Please help

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import time
cmd = "runas /user:administrator notepad.exe"
proc = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
print proc.stdout.read()
proc.communicate('password')
```

Comment: Perhaps see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238840/run-program-from-command-line-what-prompts-password-and-automatically-provide-pa?rq=1) thread. Also, perhaps you need to send a `\n` after the password?

Comment: Tried as suggested by @nbryans but no luck

Comment: You can use [`WriteConsoleInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687403) to write directly to the console input buffer. That said, `runas.exe` has a `/savecred` option to use saved credentials. The first time it prompts for the password. The saved credentials are listed in the control panel's credential manager, so in principle you can probably add them via [`CredWrite`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375187), which would allow persisting them only for the current logon session instead of permanently in the user's vault.

Comment: Just to be more clear, i am trying to open notepad using above codes from an application But its starting under SYSTEM for which the notepad is not opening (even its not asking me for password for 1st time.)

tried with /savecred, asking for password but there is no prompt to enter

Comment: Is the application a service running under the SYSTEM account in the non-interactive services session?

Comment: Yes, the application a service running under the SYSTEM account

Comment: You need to call `LogonUser` to get an access token for the Administrator account; `SetTokenInformation` to set its `TokenSessionId` to the active console session ID, as returned by `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId`; and then either `LoadUserProfile` and `CreateProcessAsUser` or `CreateProcessWithTokenW` with the flag `LOGON_WITH_PROFILE`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you open to using Pexpect instead? If yes, you can use the following:

```
import pexpect
cmd = "runas /user:administrator notepad.exe"
child_process = pexpect.spawn(cmd)
child_process.expect('assword')
child_process.sendline(password)
```

Comment: Have you tried this? IIRC pexpect on Windows uses pipes. That won't work.

Comment: You are right! There is a substitute for windows though offered by Expec

Comment: You are right! There is a substitute offered by Pexpect for windows:

Comment: Its given here: http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#pexpect-on-windows

Comment: Tried with pexpect but as suspected in WIndows, its not sending password. Instead it's giving invalid arguments error.    Anybody having idea about winexpect